# In Android how SpeechRecognizer can recognize my own app name "Vendict"?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, speech-recognition

I make app named "Vendict" and was speech recognization app like "Google Assistant".
I want to use "Ok Vendict" as startup speech like "Ok Google" but SpeechRecognizer recognize "Vendict" to "bandit".
How can I do for this?